# Year and month colorbar plots in Python and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, colorbar

I am plotting 400 days of data. One sample represents one day, totaling 400 samples. I want to color the bar based on the **month** and where the sample comes from.

Code:

```
df = 
timestamp                y_val
2019-10-01 08:10:53    0.620505
2019-11-01 08:10:57    0.720505
2019-12-01 08:10:59    0.820505
2020-01-01 08:11:02    0.920505
2020-02-01 08:11:06    0.520505
2020-03-14 13:05:22    0.629888
2020-04-14 13:05:25    0.729888
2020-05-14 13:05:27    0.829888
2020-06-14 13:05:31    0.929888
2020-07-14 13:05:33    0.429888

plt.scatter(df.index,df['y_val'],
            c=df.index.year+df.index.month/12,cmap='jet_r')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

It looks fine but the problem is colorbar appearance. It is hard to tell it is talking about year and month. Atleast, I wanted to see 2019 and 2020 there. How do I get this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plot time series with colorbar in pandas + matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51160705/plot-time-series-with-colorbar-in-pandas-matplotlib)

Comment: @Asmus This did not answer my question. My df has timestamp (date+time). I am getting weird results like (1970 Jan) in the colorbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure whether I understood your question correctly, especially regarding your request to "color the bar based on the month and where the sample comes from.". Also I'm not sure why you're trying to convert your timestamp into a float here: `df.index.year+df.index.month/12`.

Since your x-axis is already giving you the date information, I'm not too sure why you want to add the same information on the colorbar; but again, perhaps I just misunderstood your request.

In any case, try this code:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

raw="""
timestamp                y_val
2019-10-01 08:10:53    0.620505
2019-11-01 08:10:57    0.720505
2019-12-01 08:10:59    0.820505
2020-01-01 08:11:02    0.920505
2020-02-01 08:11:06    0.520505
2020-03-14 13:05:22    0.629888
2020-04-14 13:05:25    0.729888
2020-05-14 13:05:27    0.829888
2020-06-14 13:05:31    0.929888
2020-07-14 13:05:33    0.429888"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(raw),delimiter=" \s+",index_col=0, engine="python")
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

fig,ax=plt.subplots()
sca = ax.scatter(df.index,df['y_val'],c=df.index,cmap='jet_r')
cbar = plt.colorbar(sca)

cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(pd.to_datetime(cbar.get_ticks()).strftime(date_format='%b %Y'))

fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

which yields:

[image: plot with a date-formatted colorbar]

Comment: This effectively answered my question. Yes! I removed the float computation, which was unnecessary. Your color bar code did help me to realize what I wanted. Thanks a ton.